# Proof that a statement involving quantifiers is false

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I believe that the sentence $\forall x (P(x)\rightarrow \exists y Q(x,y))$ false?
Is it sufficient to define:

1) The Domain of $x, y    $

2) The predicates $P(x)$ and $Q(x,y)$

so that for some $x$ and $y$, $P(x)$ is true while $Q(x,y)$ is false?

Comment: @AhaanRungta I have an interpretation of (1) and (2) for which $P(x) \rightarrow \exists y\,Q(x,y)$ is false. My question was whether that was sufficient to prove that the sentence is false.

Comment: @EggHead It's not clear what you mean with 'false'. Do you mean to say that it isn't a [logical truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_truth)?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, I'm intepreting the sentence as stating that $P(x)\rightarrow \exists yQ(x,y)$ is logically true for all $x$. So, if I'm able to come up with a definition of P(x) and Q(x,y) under some domain, that means that the sentence is not a logical truth.

Comment: @EggHead That's is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was established in the comments that the OP knows that to prove that
$\forall x(P(x)\to\exists yQ(x,y))$ isn't a logical truth, it suffices to find domains for $x$ and $y$ and interpretations for $P$ and $Q$ such that $\forall x(P(x)\to\exists yQ(x,y))$ is false.

What was intutive for me to think about was considering $x,y$ raging over the natural numbers and letting $P(x)$ mean '$x$ is a natural number'.

Think about an order relation for $Q$ solves the problem.

Comment: Let Q(x,y): x > y

Comment: @EggHead Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

The [Tree Proof Generator](https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/) provided the following simple countermodel:

[image]

The domain contains one member, $0$. $P(0)$ is true.  There is no values from the domain for which $Q$ is true.

With this countermodel, the antecedent is true and the consequent is false.

One way to find this manually is to consider what would make $\exists yQ(xy)$ false? One way to do that is to let $Q$ be false for all values of whatever domain we come up. That makes the consequent false. Then consider how to make the antecedent, $P$, true? Let the domain contain one member and let that member make $P$ true.

---

Tree Proof Generator. https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/